# which ubuntu version is for lenovo z500 with i5-?

Tags: lenovo

which  version of ubuntu (13.10 or  12) i should install?

Your help would be great!

dps    Just clicking on About This Compute to open

Comment: Which one do you think you should use?

Answer (score 1):

*Ubuntu 13.10* is the latest stable ubuntu version.Ubuntu 13.10 will be supported for 9 months and includes cutting-edge new features that make your music, videos, documents and apps much easier to access.

*Ubuntu 12.04.3* LTS is a long-term support release. It has continuous hardware support improvements as well as guaranteed security and support updates until April 2017.

You can be able to install both the versions on your lenovo z500 laptop.